# Why is this conditional statement never executing?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, conditional-statements

I'm working through "The Java Tutorial" which Oracle published and I'm not sure why I'm not able to get the conditional statement in this example from the "Concurrency" chapter to execute:

```
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > patience) &&
                msgThread.isAlive())
```

The startTime variable is initialized above this to:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The patience variable can either be a hard-coded value (1 hour) or a value (in seconds) passed in as a command-line argument.

```
    long patience = 1000 * 60 * 60; // initially 1 hour of patience

    // if there is a command-line arg
    if (args.length > 0) {
        try {
            // takes command-line arg as seconds
            patience = Long.parseLong(args[0]) * 1000;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid commmand-line argument, " +
                "terminating...");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

The thing is, when I run the program with a variety of command-line arguments (even if I pass in 1, which should end after 1 second, I get no difference in response!), none of them actually get the conditional statement to be true, which would then interrupt the msgThread and print a message to the screen:

```
        // if the amount of time passed is more than patience and the
        // thread is still alive
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > patience) &&
            msgThread.isAlive()) {

            // "tired of waiting" to threadMessage
            threadMessage("Tired of waiting, ending thread.");
            // interrupt the thread
            msgThread.interrupt();
            // wait indefinitely for it to finish
            msgThread.join();
        }
```

Here is a sample of the console output when I run with a 1 second command-line argument:
[image]

Here is a complete copy of the code, any help understanding these results would be greatly appreciated!

```
/*
*   This program is from Chapter 13 of "The Java Tutorial". It demonstrates
*   some basic Thread funtionality by displaying 4 different messages
*   4 seconds apart in one Thread, while the other thread periodically
*   checks the total run time of the application to see if it has passed
*   a patience threshold, which is hard-coded as 1 hour but can be 
*   input by the user as a commmand-line arg in seconds. If the patience
*   threshold is reached, the main thread interrupts the message thread
*   and displays "finally!"
*/

public class SimpleThreads {
    /* 
    *  Display a message preceded by the name of the current thread.
    *  This will be called periodically throughout the program to
    *  show where we are in the app
    */
    public static void threadMessage(String message) {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n", threadName, message);
    }

    /*
    *   Private nested class that will be the Runnable object. The
    *   run() method will be called when a Thread starts execution.
    */
    private static class MessageLoop implements Runnable {
        /*
        *   Prints a message to the console every four seconds.
        *   There are 4 messages total. If interrupted, says so!.
        */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String[] message = {"msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4"};
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(4000); // throws exception if interrupted
                    threadMessage(message[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                threadMessage("I wasn't done!");
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    *   Gets the amount of time (patience) that the user will wait for the
    *   MessageLoop classes thread to complete. Starts the MessageLoop
    *   Thread and tracks the total time it runs. If it runs more than
    *   the patience allows for, the MessageLoop thread will be 
    *   interrupted.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        long patience = 1000 * 60 * 60; // initially 1 hour of patience

        // if there is a command-line arg
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                // takes command-line arg as seconds
                patience = Long.parseLong(args[0]) * 1000;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Invalid commmand-line argument, " +
                    "terminating...");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        // pass message "Starting MessageLoop thread" to threadMessage
        threadMessage("Starting MessageLoop");
        // get the currentTimeMillis and set as start time (long)
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // create a new Thread and pass it the MessageLoop runnable
        Thread msgThread = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
        // start the thread
        msgThread.start();

        // pass "Waiting for msglp thread to finish" to threadMessage
        threadMessage("Waiting for MessageLoop to finish...");

        // in a loop determined by if the thread is still alive
        while (msgThread.isAlive())

            // wait a max of 1 second for thread to finish
            msgThread.join(1000);

            // if the amount of time passed is more than patience and the
            // thread is still alive
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > patience) &&
                msgThread.isAlive()) {

                // "tired of waiting" to threadMessage
                threadMessage("Tired of waiting, ending thread.");
                // interrupt the thread
                msgThread.interrupt();
                // wait indefinitely for it to finish
                msgThread.join();
            }

        // "finally" to threadMessage
        threadMessage("Finally!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can also use an enhanced for-loop in your `run` method now:  `for (String aMessage : message) {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   while (msgThread.isAlive()) msgThread.join(1000);
```

You've probably forgot to type { after while.
And now you are waiting until the thread is finished, no matter what.

Try:

```
    // in a loop determined by if the thread is still alive
    while (msgThread.isAlive()) {

        // wait a max of 1 second for thread to finish
        msgThread.join(1000);

        // if the amount of time passed is more than patience and the
        // thread is still alive
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > patience) &&
            msgThread.isAlive()) {

            // "tired of waiting" to threadMessage
            threadMessage("Tired of waiting, ending thread.");
            // interrupt the thread
            msgThread.interrupt();
            // wait indefinitely for it to finish
            msgThread.join();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh man, I've been looking at code for too long today... Dumb mistake, thanks for catching it! I can't accept the answer for another 5 minutes for some reason but I will do so as soon as it lets me.

Comment: I noticed that type-o as well when comparing to the original source.  I think that might be it.